# DirectoryEntry CommitChanges() not supported by server

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I'm trying to change a user's property inside my AD using the following c# code:

```
DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://xxx/DC=xxx,DC=xx,DC=xx", "xxx", "xxx");          
DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(root);

directorySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectclass=user)(|(cn=Users)(cn=user001)))";

SearchResult sResultSet = directorySearcher.FindOne();
string a = (GetProperty(sResultSet, "badPwdCount"));

DirectoryEntry ADuser = new DirectoryEntry(sResultSet.Path, "xxx", "xxx");
ADuser.Properties["badPwdCount"].Value = 3;
ADuser.CommitChanges();
ADuser.Close();
```

I'm able to read the value and browse through the AD but I'm not able to commit my changes. Every time I execute `ADuser.CommitChanges();` I get the following error :

> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: Server is
>   unable to process request.

My account is part of Domain Administrator's group and I have all access rights.
What could be the error? Is it a security issue or framework/server incompatibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`badPwdCount` is a special property which is unique between domain controllers and **cannot** be manually changed by any means.

If you want to change this value because users where this value is `NULL` are causing you problems, please see my answer here:

[Active Directory property "badPwdCount"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19935175/active-directory-property-badpwdcount/19936268#19936268)

Otherwise, back to the drawing board...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually I'm just getting started with AD and I just wanted to test some basic stuff, like changing a random property of a dummy user. I didn't want to specifically change the badPwdCount field at all, it was just to make some tests... guess I choose the wrong field eheh. Anyway I tried to change the "description" field and my code works fine. Tnx again.

Comment: @VittorioJimmyCozzolino Thats some bad luck!